# External js Path providing in index.html in ionic 2 is showing as 404

Tags: ionic2

I am specifing the path in this way.

This is showing as 404.

Kindly help to solve this issue because if this path goes correct I can proceed to access data in min.js file. Kindly help me.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific

Comment: give more details about your code & files structure

Comment: my code structure will be like folders t contains node_modules, plugins, resources, src, www. Inside src index.html and inside node modules the patch contains node_modules/audio-network/build/audio-network-v1.0.4.min.js. So to access this i have given path like <script src="node_modules/audio-network/build/audio-network-v1.0.4.min.js"></script>